# How to document a word in Doxygen which is an entity name in the code, but not one in the current context?

Tags: c++, namespaces, doxygen

My program contains a namespace called 'Common' and another namespace called 'CGI'. When I write description for CGI as follows:

```
/*! \namespace CGI
  \brief The CGI - Common Gateway Interface module.
*/
```

The 'Common' word in the expansion of CGI gets linked/referenced to the namespace Common. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to prevent autolinking by putting `%` in front of the word. See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html for more details.